# Equivalent of "$elemMatch" in MongoDB Atlas search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I've MongoDB document in the below format

```
 class Candidate(Document):
  name = StringField()
  age = StringField()
  company = StringField()
  jobs = EmbeddedDocumentListField(JobMatch)
}
```

Where JobMatch is an Embedded Document

```
class JobMatch(EmbeddedDocument):
 jd_id = Long()
  stage = StringField()
```

While Searching in MongoDB for a candidate in a specific job with a specific stage, we can use $elemMatch to filter those results, for example
If candidate 1 is attached to two jobs
jd_id = 12345, stage="Sourcing"
jd_id = 3456, stage="Offer"

And candidate 2 is also attached to two jobs
jd_id = 12345, stage="Offer"
jd_id = 3456, stage="Sourcing"

If I want candidates in stage "Sourcing" with jd_id 12345, I can use $elemMatch in MongoDB Query to find those candidate. How can it be done if using MongoDB Atlas Search ? As per my understanding there is no $elemMatch available in Atlas Search.

I tried MongoDB Atlas Search documentation and could not find any relevant information`your text`

Comment: Do you need to use Atlas Search for this query? Those look like exact matches rather than fuzzy text searching?

Comment: @user20042973, you are correct these are for exact matches, however there are some other parts of documents that needs fuzzy search so I need complete search using Altas search, i.e. fuzzy part + exact match

Comment: Via [this discussion on the developer forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/search-aggragation-elemmatches-equivalent/151220) it seems that [the `embeddedDocument` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/embedded-document/) is what you are looking for. The link says it is currently in beta but also has the description that "_the `embeddedDocument` operator is similar to `$elemMatch` operator._"